# How to dynamically get date interval between date ranges

Tags: php, date, math, graph

I am trying make the interval dynamic based on the date range.

Consider this dataset:

```
$data = [
"2016-06-01": 2,
"2016-06-01": 2,
"2016-06-02": 2,
"2016-06-02": 2,
"2016-06-03": 2,
"2016-06-03": 2,
"2016-06-04": 2,
"2016-06-04": 2,
...
];
```

I want to sum the values based on date range intervals.

So for eg:

```
$start_date = "2016-06-01";

$end_date = "2016-07-01";

// some function that returns interval dates based on range
$interval_dates = [
"2016-06-01",
"2016-06-05",
"2016-06-10,
...
];
```

Based on that I iterate through the `$data` array and get the sums for intervals.

The caveat is however that the interval dates should be based on the date range:

for eg:

if `$end_date` was next year, the interval dates would look like this:

```
$interval_dates = [
"2016-06-01",
"2016-08-01",
"2016-10-01"
];
```

So the interval is based on the difference between start and end date. The bigger the difference the bigger the intervals.

So far:

```
public function getIntervalDates($start_date, $end_date, $interval = 5)
{
    $start_date = new \DateTime($start_date);

    $end_date = new \DateTime($end_date);

    // get the difference in days
    $diff_object = $start_date->diff($end_date);

    $diff_days = $diff_object->days;

    // set the interval days based on difference in days 
    // and the interval
    $interval_days = round(intval($diff_days) / $interval);

    // set the first date to given start date
    $interval_dates[] = $start_date->format("Y-m-d");

    $current_date = $start_date;


    for($i=0; $i < $interval; $i++) {

        // set interval dates by incrementing 
        // by interval days
        $current_date->add(new \DateInterval("P".$interval_days."D"));

        // Dont go beyond end date
        if($current_date < $end_date) {
            array_push($interval_dates, $current_date->format("Y-m-d"));    
        }

    }

    // add end date
    $interval_dates[] = $end_date->format("Y-m-d");

    return $interval_dates;

}
```

This solution kinda works but is not reliable.

for eg: if choosing a big range eg: 2016-06-10 TO 2020-06-10, it only returns 2 dates.

I think there must be a mathematical formula that was made to solve precisely this kind of a problem.

Comment: You can use [DatePeriod](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php) class to generate all dates between start and end based on given interval.

Comment: can you give clear sample out put you are expecting and the code you tried.

Comment: Maybe use something based on this: `$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);`

Comment: @RavinderReddy Updated